# Leafletjs Remove polygon holes

Tags: javascript, geometry, leaflet

An API question / Leaflet internals question.

Can I (without implementing my own convex hull type algorithm based on the lat/lng array) remove holes from an L.polygon() or array of lat/lng coordinates using Leaflet? Ideally correcting intersecting paths to outer boundary paths to eliminate both intersection (1) and holes (2)

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convex hull is not what you want here.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's impossible without some costum coding.

But there are many convex hull implementation available, I can give you one if you want.

Comment: Hi LSA, yep there are tons of hull algorithms, quite a few impelemented in Javascript too. Just wanted to know if there was a plugin, undocumented function or something in Leaflet as other map libraries support this type of polyline/polygon construction from lat-long points.